# Hadoop input with 100k paths cause extremely long time during splits

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-flink

I am using Flink batch API with Hadoop FileInputFormat to process a large number of input files(approx. 100k). I found it is extremely slow for job to be prepared. I found that in `FileInputFormat.getSplits()` method, it iterate all input paths and get block locations for every paths. I think it will send 100k requests to HDFS which leads to the problem. Is there any approaches to speed up the split generation procedure? I think spark and mapreduce may have a similarly problem as well. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing this parameter: *mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.list-status.num-threads*

Also, compacting those 100k files would definitely help.

Comment: It seems that the bottleneck is during getting block locations for each files. liststatus dont spend too much time.

Comment: I haven't checked myself if this is correct, but the doc says that applies to getBlockLocations op as well. mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.list-status.num-threads - The number of threads to use to list and fetch block locations for the specified input paths. Note: multiple threads should not be used if a custom non thread-safe path filter is used. https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml